# Does "apt-get purge" remove config files stored in user home dir?

Tags: apt

I used

```
sudo apt-get purge [package_name]
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

to remove an application so that on reinstalling it gets back to default configuration. But it didn't work, all previous modified configuration were still there.

On searching I found a dir in "/root/.[package_name]". Does `apt-get purge` remove config files stored in user home dir? If not then how to remove them?

Comment: If that would be the case, imagine what would happen if the sysadmin updates (= delete old + install new version of) the browser? All users would lose their personal data like bookmarks and stored passwords. `apt-get` never touches the home directories, for a good reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it only removes  shared configuration files, like those in the /etc directory.
That's because only those are installed with the package by dpkg(part of the archive).

The ones in the home folders of the users are usually created at runtime by the application(eg. wine creating the initial WINEPREFIX).

Answer (score 4):

No , it doesn't usually.

It will remove things in `/etc` (that belongs to the package) if your purge the package. that's where usually configuration files are stored.

Read [document here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)